# Why does lseek return 0?

Tags: api, macos, darwin

`lseek()` is supposed to return the position of the file descriptor.

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/DARWIN/Reference/ManPages/man2/lseek.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/lseek) says:

> Upon successful completion, lseek()
>   returns the resulting offset location
>   as measured in bytes from the
>        beginning of the file.  Otherwise, a value of -1 is returned
>   and errno is set to indicate the
>   error.

Trouble is, not even this works:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
printf("size off_t: %i\n", sizeof(off_t));

off_t pos;
pos = lseek(file, (off_t)0, SEEK_CUR);
printf("pos: %lli\n", pos);

// same result for SEEK_SET and SEEK_END
pos = lseek(file, (off_t)2352, SEEK_CUR);
printf("pos: %lli\n", pos);
```

This gives me:

```
size off_t: 8
pos: 0
pos: 0
```

Why is this? Is there an alternative to find the current offset, using the raw I/O functions? (`read`, `open`, `lseek`, …)

**Edit 1:**

I tried to make the example simpler.

Comment: Explanation of the code:  Seek 1, 2, 3, 4, ... bytes forward, printing i and the current position at each step.  sum(1..92682) is 2^32, which means pos=2^32 when i=92682.  Apparently, lseek is returning 0.

Comment: How is pos defined?  Is it off_t like i?  Or is it an int?  How is off_t defined on your system?  Is sizeof(off_t) <= 4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding #include <unistd.h> to the top.

See: http://forums.macosxhints.com/archive/index.php/t-35508.html

Basically, since you didn't `#include <unistd.h>`, the compiler is "guessing" that `lseek()` returns an int.

Probably an int is 4-bytes long, and since PPC is "big-endian" byte order, you're getting the "top" 4 bytes, which are all zero.

Include unistd.h lets the compiler realize that `lseek()` is returning an `off_t`, so you don't lose half the bytes.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Have you've got any idea why the compiler doesn't show a warning? With malloc it does it every time.

Answer (score 2):

Something else is up, probably something silly.  I tried your code, as here:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    off_t pos;
    int file ;
    if((file = open("/Users/chasrmartin/.bash_history",O_RDONLY)) == -1){
        perror(argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("size off_t: %i\n", sizeof(off_t));

    pos = lseek(file, (off_t)0, SEEK_CUR);
    printf("pos: %lli\n", pos);

    // same result for SEEK_SET and SEEK_END
    pos = lseek(file, (off_t)2352, SEEK_CUR);
    printf("pos: %lli\n", pos);

    exit(0);
}
```

and get this result:

```
bash $ gcc foo.c
bash $ ./a.out
size off_t: 8
pos: 0
pos: 2352
```

(Just to be definite, this is on Mac OS/X 10.5.6  on Intel.)

#### Update.

Or maybe it's not silly.  I just tried it on a PPC G5, and get the results you do.

#### Update 2

Okay, here's the result on a PPC:

```
$ gcc foo.c
$ ./a.out
size off_t: 8
pos: 0
pos: 0
```

Comment: The exact same code (with gs instead of chasrmartin) doesn't work for me. (OSX 10.5.6) What's your system?

Comment: Keen on writing a bug report? I'm not really, but I think I'll do it anyway.

Comment: Sure looks like it to me.  Doesn't make sense, though --- there are a *zillion* things that won't work if lseek(2) doesn't work.

Comment: I'll try next the support for long files, maybe this is only for normal files.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of file is it?  Is it a pipe by any chance?  Because if it's anything but a regular file, chances are it doesn't support seeking:

> The behavior of lseek() on devices which are incapable of seeking is implementation-defined. The value of the file offset associated with such a device is undefined.

Comment: I tried it with different files. /dev/disk1, /dev/rdisk1 and /path/to/a/normal/file (any of those should be seek-able)

Comment: I'd fstat() the file and check S_ISREG(stat.st_mode) just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the test to:

```
if ( (pos = lseek(file, (off_t)i, SEEK_CUR)) != -1 ) {
```

You are probably hitting a -1 somewhere, but you're testing for 0 here.

Comment: He is printing pos unless pos is 0.  Thus, he would be informed if pos == -1 (and would hopefully tell us).  I don't think that is the issue though.

Comment: thx for the edit strager :) been using VB.NET too much lately

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but here are a few thoughts which might help.

- Offset 0 is valid; it means you are at the beginning  of the file
- Depending on your platform, off_t may well be limited to 32 bits unsigned.
- Are you intending to seek relative to your current position?

-- MarkusQ